# Coefficient of thermal expansion on cooling and heating

Tags: thermodynamics, solid-state-physics

Apologies if this is a very basic question, but I cannot seem to find anyone else asking or answering it. Is the coefficient of thermal expansion (CTE) the same when cooling and heating a material?

Using the linear CTE as an example, if I start with a length $L_1$ and cool from $T_1$ to $T_2$, my new length $L_2$ should be $L_2=L_1(1-\alpha (T_1-T_2))$. If I instead start at $T_2$ and $L_2$ then heat to $T_1$, my final length $L_3$ should be the same as $L_1$ (assuming reversibility etc.). But,

$L_3 = L_2(1+\alpha (T_1-T_2))$

$L_3 = L_1(1-\alpha (T_1-T_2))(1+\alpha (T_1-T_2))$

$L_3 = L_1(1-\alpha^2 (T_1-T_2)^2)$

Of course, $\alpha$ is very small so the squared term is practically nothing, but it does show an inconsistency either in the definition or in my understanding. Could someone help enlighten me which one it is?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome Annie A to Physics Stack Exchange. The answers to these questions may help: ["Approximation of linear expansion coefficient"](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/441745/145491), ["Doubt in definition of linear thermal expansion"](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/461600/145491),["Coefficient of Linear Expansion (Formula)"](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/242064/145491)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the defining equation is inaccurate.  It should read $$\alpha=\frac{1}{L}\frac{dL}{dT}$$So $$\frac{L_2}{L_1}=e^{\alpha(T_2-T_1)}$$and $$\frac{L_1}{L_2}=e^{\alpha(T_1-T_2)}$$

Comment: Just like the simplification resulting in engineering strain.